# know when ffmpeg completes converting

Tags: php, ffmpeg

am using ffmpeg in one of my sites with PHP , i convert files using the php exec function , actually it did me some headache trying to figure out WHEN this ffmpeg completes the file conversion after executing the exec command :( is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you backgrounding the process?

Comment: U actually made me feel stupid right now hehe , what is backgrounding the process ?? i will be using the script on windows server and on linux server , i don't know if the exec processing are the same here and there , it's just that i worked out the paths and the converting is working , it's just i can't determine when the converting is finished .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've found, the exec function blocks until the ffmpeg conversion is complete.

For example, you can run ffmpeg like this in your PHP script:

```
exec($encode, $output);
```

(Where $encode is the ffmpeg command as a string, and $output is an array of each line of output from ffmpeg.)

For me, this exec command blocks my PHP script from continuing until ffmpeg conversion is complete, at which point my PHP script continues on, which seems to be how it is described in the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

So, you can tell when exec is complete by following the exec command with another PHP command on the next line in your script that notifies you conversion is complete, or updates a database, or what-have-you.

FYI, I believe that pushing the exec command "into the background" means running the exec command but having the PHP script continue on simultaneously (i.e. asynchronously). For running the exec command in the background, Google "PHP background exec" or "php multi-process", such as:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php#80241
http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-run-php-code-in/

Comment: Thanks friend , for some reason if the next line is linked to any process of reading/renaming/copying the output-ed file , it just won't work because the file "dows not exist" , i used a while loop to wait for the file to be created and proceed :)

Comment: Hmm... perhaps your file processing command is not quite right? To test, I would comment out your exec line and see if you can work with a file that you know does exist.